# JQ parsing of escaped quotes

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, fromjson

We have an AWS autoscaling lifecycle hook that is placing messages on an SQS queue.  We are trying to parse these with JQ, and while the format is mostly JSON, all the key/value pairs within the body object have escaped double quotes.  Can't seem to find an AWS option to not escape the quotes, or a JQ option to successfully parse them.  Example here:

```
    {
    "Messages": [
        {
            "Body": "{
\"Origin\":\"AutoScalingGroup\",
\"LifecycleHookName\":\"termination_lifecycle_hook\",
\"Destination\":\"EC2\",
\"AccountId\":\"<redacted>\",
\"RequestId\":\"65e1eaeb-1bde-42ef-93b5-ac14987a2848\",
\"LifecycleTransition\":\"autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING\",
\"AutoScalingGroupName\":\"test-um-prod-20230822043811258400000005\",
\"Service\":\"AWS Auto Scaling\",
\"Time\":\"2023-08-29T20:42:36.581Z\",
\"EC2InstanceId\":\"i-02ca28b1a415a4d48\",
\"LifecycleActionToken\":\"1e7f23b9-4a9a-4cad-9051-6039d815e9b1\"
}",
            "ReceiptHandle": "AQEBN8E7SCNS44lemWqlfMVvOl9EfGo7Yb5b+VhF5jXlw2i41pwQJFvfaAFwBEquO8SOsGyaIUfFiE9qEUQoQOgyUoz5a+Rx/yD9jq2qfz/gRcSwhfCAPHyBvhjJdIGmlyKtNnTzuL183Wti4BO4G+Z7bLzn/WiIT+JrSfn/VofI34HnB0w0Om3UYTnd6OoXuCu2WxzasyMeFcImuCYdt+5+tMzauEtsL7EVdSZwpW3S4oatkuxfzzyxHsP4X0IIKt6fwIzHzCRhi9kmo5QnZAQCnjHo+RBNZXWU9wbk3SToE3nCdLJhbups5SOHAUHLO1PwdVb7RvKMmYYdHfzoTQBLeWJ1w7MEMrhANC9uOu7cVzS0hAAc9qPLzzoV1TkIBn/0Q597cl6dNyfkWpPQEOKtUg==", 
            "MD5OfBody": "fa2bc63f28d96c532288b09831a8b73f", 
            "MessageId": "4c5b0c2c-9085-4bde-8de3-49ae3f63afd4"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, all objects except "Body" are fine, but all the key/values within "Body" are escaped.

Comment: The `Body` string does not have linebreaks in it, does it? That would make your input invalid JSON.

Comment: No, the original had no line breaks in the body.

Comment: It's not that the quotes are escaped, but that the `Body` key contains a JSON object serialized as _string_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`fromjson` function](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#convert-to-from-json) for parsing JSON-encoded values. In your case, that would be

```
jq '.Messages | .[] | .Body | fromjson'
```

Comment: Will try that...  I did see the "fromjson" in the docs, but since the entire purpose of JQ is to parse from JSON, it wasn't clear what this was for.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!
Since we mainly wanted the instanceId, what worked was:

jq -r '.Messages[].Body | fromjson | .EC2InstanceId'